# Can't log in to an app running on LocalHost - no network activity?

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js

I'm working on an app with a team. They are able to log in fine when running it on their local servers, however when I try to do so I get 'Invalide username / password' and no network activity or console errors in dev tools.

I have no idea why this could be, we're working on the exact same code - clearly it's something on my machine.

Has anyone come across anything like this before?

(Have tried other browsers and still nothing).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to check your server instalation on your machine.

For example, if you are using `XAMPP` to manage your `Apache` maybe there is some configuration that was set in the wrong way.

My advice is, save your code and re-install your server, pay attention to all configuration details and see if the problem is solved.